# Integral substitution to find constant $\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Whilst using the substitution $x = 4\sin^2\theta$, then show that this integral:

$$ \int^{3}_{0}\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}dx $$

Is equivalent to:

$$ \int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{0}\sin^2\theta d\theta $$

What I have tried:

$$ \int^{3}_{0}\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}dx=\left(\frac{x}{4-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left((4-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{-x}=\int(4-x)^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx $$

Then substituting in $x = 4\sin^2\theta$

$$ \int(4-4\sin^2\theta)^{-2\sin^2\theta}=\int \frac{2\sin^2\theta}{4-4\sin^2\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{-2\sin^2\theta}d\theta $$

Have I got the right idea?

Second approach:

1. $\int \sqrt{\frac{sin^2\theta}{1-sin^2\theta}}\cdot8\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$

identity:
$1-sin^2\theta = cos^2\theta$

2. $\int \sqrt{\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos^2\theta}}=\sqrt{tan^2\theta}=\tan\theta$

Then using the this identity:
$\tan x=\frac{sinx}{cosx}$

3. $8\int\frac{\sin\theta\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta=8\int sin^2\theta d\theta$

However, how do I get the upper integral to go from $3$ to $\frac{\pi}{3}$ likeso:
$\int^{3}_{0} \implies\int^{\frac{\pi}{3}}_{0}$?

Comment: No, this is completely wrong. How did $x$ get to the exponent?

Comment: $(\frac{x}{4-x})^{\frac{1}{2}}\ne((4-x)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{-x}$

Comment: You're wrong from the first equality. How would you just "drop" am integration operator ?

Comment: @no_'t'-lime I edited my question now. I would appreciate a tick :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all calculate the differential: $\mathrm{d}x = 8\sin\theta\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$. Your boundaries are right.
The integral is
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/3}\sqrt{\frac{4\sin^2\theta}{4(1-\sin^2\theta)}}{8\sin\theta\cos\theta}\,{\mathrm{d}\theta} = {8}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/3}{\sin^2\theta}\,{\mathrm{d}\theta} = 8{\sqrt3},$$
since $\cos\theta= \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.

**Edit 1:** In your second approach you asked how to get to the boundaries. You want to substitute $x=4\sin^2\theta$, which means that $\theta=\arcsin\sqrt{x/4}$. Putting in your earlier values for $x$ in this formula gives you your new boundaries.

**Edit 2:** Solve for $\theta$:
$$\begin{align}
x&=4\sin^2\theta\quad\mid  :4 \\\\
\frac{x}{4}&=\sin^2\theta\quad\mid  \sqrt{} \\\\
\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}&=\sin\theta\quad\mid  \sqrt{} \\\\
\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}&=\sin\theta\quad\mid  \arcsin{} \\\\
\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{x}{4}}&=\theta
\end{align}$$
Now you can set $x=0$ and $x=3$. That should give you $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi/3$.

Comment: if I replace $x$ with $4\sin^2 \theta$ into the re-arranged equation, won't I just get $\theta= \arcsin sin(\theta) = \sin(\theta)= sin(\theta)$, how does this compute $\frac{\pi}{3}$?

Comment: No you forgot about the $1/4$ and the square. First of all you divide by $4$, then you do the square root and then the arcsin. If you set $x=3$ you'll get to $\pi/3$. Note that $\sin^2\theta\equiv(\sin\theta)^2$.

Comment: I included both. I approached it likeso: $\arcsin \sqrt{\frac{4 \sin^2 (\theta)}{4}}= \arcsin \sqrt{\sin^2 (\theta)} = \arcsin[\sin(\theta)]$?

Comment: Should I do a new edit that explains everything steb by step?

Comment: Please, that would be helpful!

Comment: Do you understand it?

Comment: aha! I completely misunderstood you, now I get the picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It's much easier to make the substitution *before* integrating - and, since you want to show two integrals are equivalent, you may not even need to integrate at all. Try plugging in $x = 4\sin^2\theta$ first:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}} = \sqrt{\frac{4\sin^2\theta}{4-4\sin^2\theta}} , $$

then simplify that expression algebraically. Don't also forget to make the appropriate substitutions for $dx$ and for the limits of the integral too!